# Loop products slider with Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I want to fetch my products and loop all products with a slider. I'm trying to fetch all products with @foreach function but I'm not getting the exact view of the original slider. Please help me with how to do this slider loop. I attached my original UI & I tried code.

**Original Html code**

```
<div class="carousel slide media-carousel" id="media">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item  active">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4 style=" text-align: center; font-weight: 600 !important;">Product Name</h4>
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="./images/cap.jpg"></a>
                <p style=" text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">Product Description</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn-1">Enquiry Basket</a>
              </div>          
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4 style=" text-align: center; font-weight: 600 !important;">Product Name</h4>
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="./images/cap.jpg"></a>
                <p style=" text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">Product Description</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn-1">Enquiry Basket</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4 style=" text-align: center; font-weight: 600 !important;">Product Name</h4>
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="./images/cap.jpg"></a>
                <p style=" text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">Product Description</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn-1">Enquiry Basket</a>
              </div>        
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4 style=" text-align: center; font-weight: 600 !important;">Product Name</h4>
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="./images/cap.jpg"></a>
                <p style=" text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">Product Description</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn-1">Enquiry Basket</a>
              </div>          
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4 style=" text-align: center; font-weight: 600 !important;">Product Name</h4>
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="./images/cap.jpg"></a>
                <p style=" text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">Product Description</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn-1">Enquiry Basket</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4 style=" text-align: center; font-weight: 600 !important;">Product Name</h4>
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="./images/cap.jpg"></a>
                <p style=" text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">Product Description</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn-1">Enquiry Basket</a>
              </div>        
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4 style=" text-align: center; font-weight: 600 !important;">Product Name</h4>
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="./images/cap.jpg"></a>
                 <p style=" text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">Product Description</p>
                 <a href="#" class="btn-1">Enquiry Basket</a>
              </div>          
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4 style=" text-align: center; font-weight: 600 !important;">Product Name</h4>
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="./images/cap.jpg"></a>
                 <p style=" text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">Product Description</p>
                 <a href="#" class="btn-1">Enquiry Basket</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4 style=" text-align: center; font-weight: 600 !important;">Product Name</h4>
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="./images/cap.jpg"></a>
                 <p style=" text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">Product Description</p>
                 <a href="#" class="btn-1">Enquiry Basket</a>
              </div>      
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#media" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
        <a data-slide="next" href="#media" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
      </div>                          
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My issues each row have to show 3 products only. 1st active row has 3 images other rows have each 3 product details.

**I tried code**

```
<div class="carousel slide media-carousel" id="media">
        <div class="carousel-inner">

        @foreach($Product as $Pro)

        @if($loop->first)
          <div class="item active">
        @else
          <div class="item">
        @endif
            <div class="row">

                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <h4 style=" text-align: center; font-weight: 600 !important;">{{$Pro->product_name}}</h4>
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="{{$Pro->product_name}}" src="{{asset($Pro->prod_image1)}}"></a>
                        <p style=" text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">{{$Pro->prod_short_description}}</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn-1">Enquiry Basket</a>
                      </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        @endforeach
        </div>
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#media" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
        <a data-slide="next" href="#media" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This is my controller function**

```
public function showHome()
    {
        $arr["Product"] = product::where('prod_flag','1')->get();
        return view('index')->with($arr);
    }
```

[image]

It's coming to each row one product is showing

Comment: could you please show current view

Comment: I attached the images.

Comment: dd() the collection and show me the result

Comment: http://newgwsbs.gwshosting.com.au/

Check this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the thing is you are still looping a single `product.product::where('prod_flag','1')->get();` return a collection and you are looping that collection. So you are looping a row all the time means that there will be only one image inside a row and that row contains a single `col-md-4`.

```
 <div class="row">

                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <h4 style=" text-align: center; font-weight: 600 !important;">{{$Pro->product_name}}</h4>
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="{{$Pro->product_name}}" src="{{asset($Pro->prod_image1)}}"></a>
                        <p style=" text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">{{$Pro->prod_short_description}}</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn-1">Enquiry Basket</a>
                      </div>

            </div>
```

So what you have to do is chunk the collection into sub collection via collection chunk() method like below.

```
$products = product::where('prod_flag','1')->get()->chunk(3);
```

This will out put something like below

```
0 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1792 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▶]
}
1 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1795 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▶]
}
2 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1794 ▶}
3 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1793 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▶]
```

As you can see now there are 3 products within one collection. So now you all have to do is just loop the collection and then within that loop ,loop the array. Something like below

```
     @foreach($Product as $Pro)

        @if($loop->first)
          <div class="item active">
        @else
          <div class="item">
        @endif
            <div class="row">

@foreach($Pro as $singlePro)
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <h4 style=" text-align: center; font-weight: 600 !important;">{{$singlePro->product_name}}</h4>
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="{{$singlePro->product_name}}" src="{{asset($singlePro->prod_image1)}}"></a>
                        <p style=" text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">{{$Pro->prod_short_description}}</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn-1">Enquiry Basket</a>
                      </div>
@endforeach
            </div>
          </div>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: I did the chunk function In dd() it's 3,3,1 but if send to index it's giving an error

Comment: I send you to request in linkedin.